# Get table field max value from Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have a field in my table defined as:

```
"SECTION" NUMBER(3,0)
```

The hbm mapping for this field is:

```
<property name="section" type="integer">
    <column name="SECTION" />
</property>
```

In the entity class I declare it as:

```
private Integer section;
```

In my DAO, before inserting the data, I'd like to validate and throw an exception if the data I get is too large for the section field.

What I have so far using the LocalSessionFactoryBean that I get from my application context:

```
int length = ((Column) localSessionFactoryBean.
           getConfiguration().
           getClassMapping(MyEntity.class.getName()).
           getProperty("section").
           getColumnIterator().next()).getLength();
```

The problem is that for each field declared as integer, the length is always 255.

How can I get the column length defined in oracle? (here: number(3,0))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, instead of trying to access the column definition, just use [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/) on your POJO?

Comment: With this solution I need to hardcode a max @Size for each property of the pojo I want to validate. That would be our last resort if we can't make it work dynamically.

Comment: I ended up using this as it's clean and easy.